# Extract Title Tags BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup, tags, title

I need help because I wanted to write code for finding out the title tags on a website. Although I used the code from another question and applied it to this scenario, there are no title tags whenever I print 'Beschreibung'.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import urllib.parse

webseite = 'https://www.entega.de/sitemap/'
response = requests.get(webseite)
response.status_code
soup = BeautifulSoup (response.content, 'html.parser')


result_container = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'clearfix'})

url_part_1 = 'https://www.entega.de/sitemap/'

url_part_2 = []

for item in result_container:
    for link in item.find_all ('a', {'class':'modSitemap__lvl1Link ui-link' }):
        url_part_2.append (link.get ('href'))

url_joined = []

for i in url_part_2:
    url_joined.append (urllib.parse.urljoin(url_part_1,i))

Überschrift = []
Beschreibung = []
Verlinkungen = []

for link in url_joined: 
    response = requests.get (link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup (response.content, 'html.parser')
    Beschreibung.append(soup.find_all('a', title=True, class_='modSitemap__lvl1Link ui-link'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting nothing because these links don't have an `<a class="modSitemap__lvl1Link ui-link">` tag. They do have classes that start with that string though. You could expand to that. Or you can simply just get the `<a>` tags that have a `title` attribute.

So change your loop to either:

```
import re
for link in url_joined: 
    response = requests.get (link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup (response.content, 'html.parser')
    Beschreibung.append(soup.find_all('a', {'class':re.compile("^modSitemap__lvl1Link ui-link")}, title=True, ))
```

or

```
for link in url_joined: 
    response = requests.get (link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup (response.content, 'html.parser')
    Beschreibung.append(soup.find_all('a', title=True))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I think you solved my other problem as well. So I can use the re.compile for scraping through all 'modSitemap__lvl' arguments? Or do I use CSS selectors. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Basically, I don't know how to handle this issue: for item in result_container:
    for link in item.find_all ('a', {'class':'modSitemap__lvl1Link ui-link' }):
        url_part_2.append (link.get ('href')) . Should I make it with Regex or CSS ? The reason I ask is because there are three modSitemap__lvl(1,2,3)Link ui-LInk

Comment: whats the issue?

Comment: Basically, I want to standardize a script for scraping a website. The importance is on dividing the perspective on each sub page to sort them in the end (in pandas). For example sub page 'Sales'. Then I would like to gain the information out of this subpage and transfer this into my pandas and in consequence into an xlsx

Comment: That's why I need to scrape multiple sub pages at once that do not have the exact same class

Comment: Hey can you please help me I @chitown88 because I am not able to execute the process -  There are three 'modSitemap__lvl1Link ui-link' of those classes. 'modSitemap__lvl2Link ui-link' 'modSitemap__lvl3Link ui-link' I want to scrape them all thats why I need a solution for this part : or link in item.find_all ('a', {'class':'modSitemap__lvl1Link ui-link' }):

Comment: yes you could use regex for that too. It would look like: `{'class':re.compile("^modSitemap__lvl[\d]Link ui-link")}`